# Prob 8, Sec 7 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY 2nd ed: How do we show these sets have the same cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Here's Prob. 8. Sec. 7 in *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ denote the two element set $\{0,1\}$; let $\mathscr{B}$ be the set of *countable* subsets of $X^{\omega}$. Show that $X^{\omega}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ have the smae cardinality.

Here $X^{\omega}$ denotes the set of all infinite binary sequences (i.e., the set of all the functions each with domain the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers and range a (non-empty) subset of $\{0,1\}$).

My effort:

Using the Schroeder Bernstein theorem, our aim is to show the existence of injective maps $f \colon X^{\omega} \to \mathscr{B}$ and $g \colon \mathscr{B} \to X^{\omega}$.

We can define $f$ as follows: 
$$f(s) \colon= \{s\} \ \mbox{ for all } \ s \in X^{\omega}.$$

How do we define our desired map $g$?

Answer (score 5):

You can't quite define an injection from $\scr B$ into $X^\omega$. The reason is that it is consistent with the failure of the axiom of choice that there is no such injection.

This means that you have, at some point, resort to using the axiom of choice. Luckily, we can fine a surjection from $X^\omega$ onto $\scr B$, by noting that $(X^\omega)^\omega$ and $X^\omega$ have the same cardinality. Therefore we can think of every element of $X^\omega$ as encoding a sequence of elements of $X^\omega$.

Can you see how does that help you in obtaining the surjection?

Comment: Lest my answer and Asaf's seem at odds, let me point out my use of sequences instead of sets. Indeed, I'm not off the hook - the final part of my answer breaks down if you don't assume the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose I have a countable sequence $C=(S_n)_{n\in\omega}$ of infinite binary sequences - say, $S_n=(a_i^n)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. I can view $C$ as an $\omega$-by-$\omega$ array of $0$s and $1$s. Can you see how to turn an $\omega$-by-$\omega$ array into an infinite sequence? (HINT: why is $\mathbb{N}^2\cong\mathbb{N}$?)

---

OK, fine, the above was talking about countable *sequences* of elements of $X^\omega$. But how does the set of countable subsets compare to the set of countable sequences?

Comment: so nice of you! Munkres defines a set to be countably infinite if there is a bijection of the set with the set of naturals. And he defines a set to be countable if it is either finite or countably infinite. Could you please review your posts to see if it is in need of revision in this light? Could you please also elaborate on how the map you've proposed is injective?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud I am aware of what "countably infinite" means; there is no need for my answer to be revised. There are two separate  maps implicit in this answer: (1) an injection from $\{$countable subsets of $X^\omega\}$ to $\{$infinite sequences of elements of $X^\omega\}$; and (2) an injection from $\{$infinite sequences of elements of $X^\omega\}$ to $X^\omega$. The former exists via the axiom of choice (and some choice is necessary, see Asaf's answer below); finding the latter is a good exercise.